# How to delete data from Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I created one table in Google App Engine. I stored and retrieved data from Google App Engine.
However, I don't know how to delete data from Google App Engine Datastore.

Comment: Typo in the title, please correct it to support search

Answer (score 4):

An application can delete an entity from the datastore using a model instance or a Key. The [model instance's delete()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_delete) method deletes the corresponding entity from the datastore. The [delete() function](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#delete) takes a Key or list of Keys and deletes the entity (or entities) from the datastore:

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE msg_date < :1", earliest_date)
results = q.fetch(10)
for result in results:
    result.delete()

# or...

q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM Message WHERE msg_date < :1", earliest_date)
results = q.fetch(10)
db.delete(results)
```

Source and further reading:

- [Google App Engine: Creating, Getting and Deleting Data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Deleting_an_Entity)

If you want to delete all the data in your datastore, you may want to check the following Stack Overflow post:

- [How to delete all datastore in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062540/how-to-delete-all-datastore-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the entity then you need delete it.

So in python it would be

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM Message WHERE create_date < :1", earliest_date)
results = q.get()
db.delete(results)
```

or in Java it would be

```
pm.deletePersistent(results);
```

URLS from app engine are

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Deleting_an_Object
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Deleting_an_Entity

Answer (score 0):

In Java

I am assuming that you have an endpoint:

```
Somethingendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder).build();
```

And then:

```
endpoint.remove<ModelName>(long ID);
```