# How fast are App Engine db.get(keys) and A.all(keys_only=True).filter('b =', b).fetch(1000)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

A db.get() of 50 keys seems to take me 5-6 seconds. Is that normal? What is the time a function of?

I also did a A.all(keys_only=True).filter('b =', b).fetch(1000) where A.b is a ReferenceProperty. I did 50 such round trips to the datastore, with different values of b, and the total time was only 3-4 seconds.

How is this possible? db.get() is done in parallel, with only one trip to the datastore, and I would think that looking up an entity by key is a faster operation than fetch.

Here is the definition for my class A:

```
class App(db.Model):
    name_atom = db.ReferenceProperty(AppName)
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author)
    short_desc = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty()
    url = db.StringProperty()
    rating_avg = properties.RangeProperty(0, 1000, default=0)
    rating_count = properties.RangeProperty(min_value=0, default=0)
    add_dt = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    modify_dt = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

**Update**

OK, AppStats says: `datastore_v3.Get  real=2272ms api=416ms`

I think what's happening is that I'm doing this db.get([50 keys]) right after a ton of other inefficient datastore calls in the same request handler, and it's just rate limiting me or something. Other times I've done the same db.get() and it returned in 200ms :)

Comment: It might be helpful to see the model(s) that you're fetching with your `db.get()` call.

Comment: OK, edited to add model definition.

Comment: Don't leave us hanging!  Did you figure out why your 50 key get was so slow?

Comment: Not yet :) will update when I do.

Comment: Updated. I think everything makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A db.get() of 50 keys seems to take me
>   5-6 seconds. Is that normal? What is
>   the time a function of?

No. It should take a couple of hundred milliseconds. How are you timing it, though?

> I also did a
>   A.all(keys_only=True).filter('b =',
>   b).fetch(1000) where A.b is a
>   ReferenceProperty. I did 50 such round
>   trips to the datastore, with different
>   values of b, and the total time was
>   only 3-4 seconds.

That's not unreasonable, for 50 roundtrips.

> How is this possible? db.get() is done
>   in parallel, with only one trip to the
>   datastore, and I would think that
>   looking up an entity by key is a
>   faster operation than fetch.

It's an extremely odd result, and I think that there are likely confounding factors at work. As David suggests, you should use AppStats to discover where the time is going.

Answer (score 2):

When fetching entities by key, query time should primarily be dependent on the size of your entities.  The entities have to be transferred to you over the network and then decoded.

Perhaps your entities are quite large?  This might explain why your `keys_only` query is faster despite the fact it includes a filter and fetches many more results.

You might consider using [AppStats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) so you can see exactly why your request is taking so long.  You could even post it along with your question.

Comment: All entities in my datastore are tiny, like < 5kb.

Comment: It's also worth noting that even though I said .fetch(1000) in my filter query, it would only match like ~1 entity for each of the 500 queries :)