# Wiping the datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm working on an app engine project (java). I'm using the jdo interface. I haven't pushed the application yet (just running at localhost). Is there a way I can totally wipe my datastore after I publish? In eclipse, when working locally, I can just wipe the datastore by deleting the local file:

```
appengine-generated/local_db.bin
```

any facility like that once published?

I'm using jdo right now, but I might switch to objectify or slim3, and would want a convenient way to wipe my datastore should I switch over, or otherwise make heavy modifications to my classes.

Otherwise it seems like I have to setup methods to delete instances myself, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can delete it from admin console if there are not much enitty stored in your app. go to http://appengine.google.com and manually do it. easy for less than 2000-5000 entity.

Comment: I mean otherwise though, we need to write some methods to keep deleting entities, though, right?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062540/how-to-delete-all-datastore-in-google-app-engine) addressed the same topic.  There is no one command way to drop an entire datastore's worth of data.  The only suggestion I have beyond those give in that previous question, would be to try out the new Mapper functionality, which would make it easy to map over an entire set of entities, deleting them as you went.