# Google App Engine : use mapreduce to empty datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, mapreduce

I am trying to use an [early experimental release of mapper implementation](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) to empty the datastore.  This solution was proposed in a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062540/how-to-delete-all-datastore-in-google-app-engine/3621227#3621227).

This is the **AppEngineMapper** I am currently using. It just deletes the entity.

```
public class EmptyFixesMapper extends AppEngineMapper<Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable> {

    public EmptyFixesMapper() {
    }

    @Override
    public void taskSetup(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void taskCleanup(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        super.setup(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup(Context context) {
        getAppEngineContext(context).flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void map(Key key, Entity value, Context context) {
        log.warning("Mapping key: " + key);

        DatastoreMutationPool mutationPool = 
                    this.getAppEngineContext(context).getMutationPool();
        mutationPool.delete(value.getKey());
    }
}
```

This is my **mapreduce.xml** configuration file:

```
<configurations>
    <configuration name="Empty Entities">
        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
            <value>com.google.appengine.demos.mapreduce.EmptyFixesMapper</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>
            <value>com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.DatastoreInputFormat</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name human="Entity Kind to Map Over">mapreduce.mapper.inputformat.datastoreinputformat.entitykind</name>
            <value template="optional">Fix</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
...
```

When I enter the the **mapreduce control panel** in mydomain/mapreduce/status, I can launch the tasks, but they never complete.  This is the screenshot where you can see a field "0/0 shards":

[image: mapreduce control panel]

And I can see some tasks are created in the **appengine default task queue**, with a lot of retries:

[image: appengine task queue]

An finally, in my GAE application logs I see:

> 1.
>         09-11 03:23AM 08.556 /mapreduce/mapperCallback 500 10081ms
>   0cpu_ms 0kb AppEngine-Google;
>   (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
>
> ```
>   0.1.0.2 - - [11/Sep/2010:03:23:18 -0700] "POST
> ```
>
> /mapreduce/mapperCallback HTTP/1.1"
>   500 0
>   "http://xxx.appspot.com/mapreduce/command/start_job"
>   "AppEngine-Google;
>   (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
>   xxx.appspot.com" ms=10081 cpu_ms=0
>   api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000057
>   queue_name=default
>   task_name=worker-attempt-1284198892815-0001-m-000002-1--0
>
> 2.
>         W 09-11 03:23AM 18.638
>
> ```
>   Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service
> ```
>
> your request. This may happen
>   sporadically when the App Engine
>   serving cluster is under unexpectedly
>   high or uneven load. If you see this
>   message frequently, please contact the
>   App Engine team.

What could be happening?  I'm sure I've followed steps described in the [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInJava), and I have less than 1000 entities in the datastore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem has nothing to do with appengine-mapreduce.  I was securing /mapreduce/** URIs, so the task in the default task queue was not being able to reach /mapreduce/mapperCallback, /mapreduce/command/start_job, etc because no username/password information is sent.

It is an interesting issue anyway, because I don't really want to open /mapreduce/** to everyone...

Comment: Tasks run with admin role, so you can (and should) secure /mapreduce/** uri's. Aborted requests will usually go away and tasks that are aborted will be retried.