# Google App Engine (Java) local datastore elements resurrecting even after deleting local_db.bin and cleaning my project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-eclipse-plugin

**

### GAE/J, Eclipse, Local Datastore:

**

I have changed my data model, including the structure of one of my entity classes. In an attempt to start over with my data, I followed the advice of JohnIdol in this SO answer:

[How to delete all datastore in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062540/how-to-delete-all-datastore-in-google-app-engine/1062553#1062553)

Somehow, even after deleting local_db.bin and cleaning, the old structure re-appears. In this screenshot, you can see one of the properties with its old name, "organizationAliasKeys," which should now be "orgAliasKeys:"

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6919071/Captures/2010-11-28_2035.png

Where is the old ghost of my data coming from? How do I kill it all the way?

Comment: after deleting local_db.bin, is there any data in the data viewer?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you need to stop the dev server before deleting local_db.bin.