# Stop datastore being deleted between app redeployments

Tags: google-app-engine

Every time I deploy my application to google app engine, the datastore for the app is cleared. Can this be turned off so that any data that is persisted to the datastore is not deleted between app re-deployments?

To deploy I right click on the project within Eclipse, select 'google' then select 'Deploy to App Engine'

Comment: Dear God. AFAIK this is not default behavior. Would you be able to provide more information about how you are deploying?

Comment: @bernie I've updated the question to describe how I deploy the project

Comment: Judging from this question/answers ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062540/how-to-delete-all-datastore-in-google-app-engine ) it seems to require a process to be able to do something like this.  Are there any delete-queries in your code? TBH, I'm grasping for straws right now.

Comment: There are no delete queries within my app. I figured it was a just a setting that could be turned on or off.

Comment: Also, how do you know the datastore is empty? Are you looking at the admin interface?

Comment: @thanks, I checked the datastore and it actually was'nt being deleted. Some code in the app was causing the data not to be displayed. If you put your suggestion into a comment I can accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be the case that the datastore is not actually empty, and that something in your code is causing the data to not be displayed.

Comment: (And to verify that you can use the Datastore Viewer in the Admin Console.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this in the development environment? That can be the behaviour there if you or your ide are deleting the relevant files.

Comment: i think/hope that this is the case.