# How can I periodically delete all the entries from a GAE datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I use the Google App Engine datastore for temporary data storage. I need some way of automatically deleting every entry in a datastore model, every x hours.

How do I do this within Google App Engine? My app uses the Python runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete all datastore in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062540/how-to-delete-all-datastore-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Scheduled Tasks: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

> The App Engine Cron Service allows you to configure regularly
>   scheduled tasks that operate at defined times or regular intervals.
>   These tasks are commonly known as cron jobs. These cron jobs are
>   automatically triggered by the App Engine Cron Service. For instance,
>   you might use this to send out a report email on a daily basis, to
>   update some cached data every 10 minutes, or to update some summary
>   information once an hour.
>
> A cron job will invoke a URL, using an HTTP GET request, at a given
>   time of day. An HTTP request invoked by cron can run for up to 10
>   minutes, but is subject to the same limits as other HTTP requests.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. We have several cron taks and it works really well.