# How can I remove unused indexes in Google App Engine Development server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How can I remove unused indexes in Google App Engine Development server

As per the [gae docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp?csw=1#Python_Deleting_unused_indexes), to remove unused indexes from production:

```
appcfg.py vacuum_indexes myapp/
```

Context:

My local development server has following datastore statistics(so i need to clean it):

```
Scanned 92650 entities of total 30233678 bytes, 3231365 index entries of total 130379677 bytes and 46394 composite index entries of total 20310492 bytes. Inserted 442 new records.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an indirect solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634631/1443563

To delete all data on development server, issue the following on cmd prompt:

```
/path/to/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore yes myappname/
```

where myappname is your directory containing your app.yaml file for the app
you need to cd to this directory path

This deletes the autogenerated indexes along with the entities

If anyone knows how to do this without deleting the entities, please share the solution

credit: Steven Almeroth and Melllvar